# Prevent to serialize input

Tags: jquery, html

I have select option box.

```
<form class="i-hate-u">
   <select class="helloMoto" name="helloMoto">
      <option value="">Select...</option>
      <option value="-1">Other</option>
   </select>
</form>
```

When the end-user select "other" option, text input appear like this :

```
$('.helloMoto').on('change', function() {
      if ($(this).val() == '-1')
            $(this).hide();
            var input_name = $(this).attr('name');
            var input = '<div class="input-group">' +
                             '<input type="text" class="form-control" name="'+input_name+'" placeholder="Type other.">' +
                              '<span class="input-group-btn">' +
                                     '<button class="btn btn-primary" onclick="removeSelectOther(this);"><i class="la la-close"></i></button>' +
                              '</span>' +
                        '</div>';

            $(this).parent().append(input);
});
```

At the end of this, when the end-user click save button, i serialize whole form like this :

```
var data = $('.i-hate-u').serialize();
```

As you can see, if the user selected an other option, input appear with same name. I want to remove if user select other option. Is there any way to if serialized value has same name, skip first one or -1.

Comment: In your event handler, just remove the `name` attribute from the `select`, if choice is -1 else, add it back.

Comment: @MatJ i found that way, but is it work every browser ? Will serialize method does not see nameless input in all browsers?

Comment: Yes, it wont, even if it sees, it wont know which key to use, in all cases, your server will see right value for the key `helloMoto`

Comment: use the attribute `disabled` on inputs that you do not want serialized

Comment: @user3154108, that prevents user from changing the value again.

Comment: Do set disabled on submit, not on change then

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just before serializing, check if the `value` for `helloMoto` is `-1` if yes then disable the `<select>` like(on form submit):

```
if($('select[name="helloMoto"]').val() == -1)
{
    $('select[name="helloMoto"]').attr('disabled', true);
}
```

Alternatively you can try, just exclude the `helloMoto`while serialization:

```
if($('select[name="helloMoto"]').val() == -1)
{
    var data = $('input[name!=security]', $('.i-hate-u')).serialize();
}else 
{
    var data = $('.i-hate-u').serialize();
}
```